# Bit Bucket Pipeline Docker Image

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

Is there somewhere out there a docker image with composer, phpunit and codeception installed. That I can use for bit bucket pipelines?

Or is there another way to prevent Composer from being installed in every build?

Comment: Create your own Dockerfile based on alpine with all required dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Composer as a official image, but I guess you have to install codeception. Composer and phpunit (which is only a php script) should work: https://hub.docker.com/_/composer/